# Problem with fetched data put into and object

Tags: javascript, object, fetch

I fetched a random image (it is object) from api and I wanted to put this into an object in object to work with this image. When I am console logging 'data' everything it's alright and I can see this image object, but when I am console logging 'data.image' the console returns me an empty object where it should be the fetched object. I am beginner.

```
let data = {
   image: {},
   votes: []
}


async function getImage() {
    let img = await fetch(data.getImgUrl, {
        method: "GET",
    })

    const newImg = await img.json();
    data.image = await newImg[0]
}
```

> When i am console logging 'data'

console log me: image{and here are attributes that contain to this fetched data} and votes: [ ]

> When i am console logging 'data.image'

console log me: image{as an empty object}

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain what you are trying t o achieve? Please provide console log output as well.

Comment: @jedi he wants to decode the image but uses JSON method on a non JSON source.

Answer (score 0):

You fetch an image but you try to decode it to JSON. This will not work. You would need to do something like below, (which I haven't written), I have it from [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/fetching-images-with-the-fetch-api-fb8761ed27b2) It is using arrayBuffer.

```js
// we use this to get the immage from the buffer
function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
  var binary = '';
  var bytes = [].slice.call(new Uint8Array(buffer));
  bytes.forEach((b) => binary += String.fromCharCode(b));
  return window.btoa(binary);
};

fetch(request, options).then((response) => {
  response.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {    
    // make an image from the buffer
    var imageStr = arrayBufferToBase64(buffer);
   // use image where you want. e.g. out it into an image tag
    document.querySelector('img').src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ imageStr;
  });
});
```

This might be also worth reading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Comment: Thanks i'll tryna figure it out